# HTTPS login using command line

Tags: command-line, authentication, https, passwords

I want to login to HTTPS website using command line, so I can make a script to check if the login is working or not.

You help will appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not a big deal, try the following command :

```
wget -O- --user=foobar --password=qux  "https://domain.tld/path"
```

Works by default on Unix and Unix like OS and for [windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)